# Yii2 Cors Filter - randomly missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: yii2, http-headers, cors, cross-domain, access-control

I have created a small API to request some data from a different domain. In the controller I have set up the Cors Filter using default values (API will be public, so I need to allow all origins):

```
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'corsFilter' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
        ]
    ];
}
```

Problem is that the request sometimes returns error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I get this error only in a few cases:

```
/api/transfer/destinations/airport-1
/api/transfer/destinations/airport-2
/api/transfer/destinations/airport-3
/api/transfer/destinations/airport-4
/api/transfer/destinations/airport-16
/api/transfer/destinations/airport-19
```

I have airports with codes from airport-1 to airport-27, all of the codes, except the ones mentioned above, work.

I have noticed that requests that are missing the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, have `Content-Length` above 4000, while others have `Content-Length` below 3000. I am not sure if this could be the issue and if it is I don't know how to solve it using Cors filter.

I have not been able to find any information about this type of a bug.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn’t that your browser has stale copies of those responses that it cached before you set up the CORS filter on the server? Have you looked in the Network pane of browser devtools to see if the browser is using copies from its cache rather than re-fetching those? Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: I have cleared cache and even tried testing from different browsers. Only solution I have found is to manually set the header in the action using [header();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? (You can find it by going to the Network pane in your browser devtools and reloading and then examining the response details there.)

Comment: @sideshowbarker It returns 200, but it might be an error on my part. I know that the method works - only thing that is missing is that header and only for  several destinations. Adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header manually fixes the problem. But it still bugs me, as this problem, theoretically, should not exist.